# how to call multiple functions with 1 live click?

Tags: jquery

I have a code like this:

```
$("button[value^='SAVEALL']").live("click",function(){
    rowCheck(1);
    rowCheck(2);
    columnCheck(A);
    columnCheck(B);
    alert("all function passed");
});

function rowCheck(x){
        if (x>10){
              return false;
        }
}

function columnCheck(a){
        if (a=="A"){
              return false;
        }
}
```

The code above, it only running the 1st function then it directly submits the form. 
How to make sure it runs all the functions and submit the form once they all return `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need your function to return both true or false
like

```
function rowCheck(x){
    if (x>10){
          return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function columnCheck(a){
    if (a=="A"){
          return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

then in change your code for click

```
$("button[value^='SAVEALL']").live("click", function(){
    if(rowCheck(1) && rowCheck(2) && columnCheck(A) && columnCheck(B))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
        //alert("all function pass");
});
```

Comment: The return statements have no meanings. If he's trying to prevent the submit from happening, he should `return false;` in the click function, not an underlying function. The returned booleans have no use whatsoever. Also, I severely dislike the use of things like `if(some_statement) { return true; } return false;`. Just return the boolean against which you are checking.

Comment: @Flater, Just return the boolean against which you are checking. I agree with you.

Comment: thanks yograj, it working now, but need to digest why it need to code that way? code in true and false for function .....

Comment: I added my own answer because I feel the coder is obfuscating his own code here. I understand you tried to answer without reworking his entire code (hence the useless if blocks still in place), but the code presented by the poster is inherently flawed; I think it's cause by using unclear coding structures and function meanings.

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
$("button[value^='SAVEALL']").live("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    rowCheck(1);
    rowCheck(2);
    columnCheck(A);
    columnCheck(B);
    alert("all function pass");
});
```

Comment: the functions just return false, nothing else, this does not apply to the function that is on the click... check the answer of @Yograj Gupta

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the event correctly. Here's what I would do:

```
$("button[value^='SAVEALL']").live("click",function(event){
    if( rowCheck(1) || rowCheck(2) || columnCheck(A) || columnCheck(B) ) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});

function rowCheck(x){
        return (x>10);
}

function columnCheck(a){
        return (a=="A");
}
```

Major changes:

- For code readability, I switched the meaning of the returned values. You're using so many boolean inversion the code becomes unclear. the functions will return `true` if the event must be stopped, not the other way around.
- instead of returning `false`, which is an unreadable piece of  code, just use `event.preventDefault();`. Much cleaner and more readable. Keep in mind that I've had to change your `function() {` to `function(event) {`!! The click event is passed by the browser, it's much better to stop that from happening than it is to rely on some outdated technique of returning `false`.
- **NEVER** use code blocks like `if(some_boolean) { return true; }`. It's a bad habit and it does not increase readability in the slightest.

This is because:

```
if ( name=="John" && lastname =="Smith") {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Can always be rewritten as:

```
return ( name=="John" && lastname =="Smith");
```

Comment: dear flater, you way also working but i only able to click one right.